# iowait CPU usage excessively high

Tags: 16.04, server, lts, docker, iowait

So I've been trying to diagnose an issue with my Ubuntu Server VM running super slow. I run Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS with docker installed. I've been using netdata to try and monitor system stats and it's showing my value for iowait as about 60% constantly. 
I feel like it could be because I have all my docker config and data directories located on an SMB share. 
I also use transmission and have around 500 torrents on it. Could this be the issue? (In amongst a bunch of other containers)

Not sure how to go about fixing it though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SMB shares with lots of active usage can definitely be the source of large iowait, but not necessarily. To debug, I suggest you install the 'iotop' package, which is like 'top' but shows IO processes.

```
sudo apt install iotop
```

Then after installing, run:

```
iotop
```

You'll see a running list of which processes are using IO.

Comment: So i ran iotop and im not seeing anything that is obviously using allot in terms of disk usage, in fact its 0 read and write most of the time which is kind of unusual. Any ideas what else could be doing it? EDIT - Aswell as that I looked at the actual disk usage stats and its showing really low numbers on disk usage which is odd

Comment: IO wait doesn't necessarily/only mean disk operations -- it can also mean that it's waiting for network resources, ie. responses from your SMB share. Based on your not seeing anything using disk resources with iotop, I think your initial suspicion about that was likely correct.

Comment: Sure, I might try cloning all my configs onto the local VM disk and then running them locally with a network backup using rclone, bit more complex but it might work a little better. Ill check back once im done to let you know if my suspicion was right